# Laptop screen black

Tags: boot, laptop, display

A ***normal*** boot up of my laptop (Acer Aspire 7750G, Windows 7) is:

- First, the "Acer" logo is shown
- Then the "Starting windows" animation is shown
- Then the blue/green log in screen is loaded (where the user accounts are shown or you have to press ctrl+alt+delete, depending on laptop).

My ***problem*** at booting is however:

- The "Acer" logo is appearing for half a second (not even filling the entire screen, but 1/3 from the top), then goes black
- The "Starting windows" is shown continuously if the animation hasn't started (with a few blinks of the screen), but as soon the animation is starting (the windowslogo is starting to appear), the screen becomes black again.
- After this the mouse pointer is shown, before the blue/green log in screen shows up (which is normal), but after a second (before the log in screen shows up) the screen goes black again (without pointer).

Does anyone have an idea what is possibly wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you changed any properties of the hard drive or BIOS recently? Sounds similar to a problem I've seen where the hard drive is set to Legacy instead of ACHI in BIOS (or vise versa?)

Comment: No, i didn't change anything or any of the BIOS/hard drive, I just used it normally. However, I do close the lid without manually press "shut down" or "sleep"

Comment: Maybe a hibernation (hybrid sleep) resume issue?

Comment: No, this booting issue occur for a regular boot (so after the laptop has been shut down)